# Undefined is not an object only for some variables in my constructor

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a pretty straightforward problem, but I can't see to figure out why it happens. I have a component in which I declare two arrays in my constructor:

```
class FilterModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.transport_options = ["driving", "tram", "walking"];
        this.pressed_percentages = ["allPressed", "under15Pressed","under30Pressed", "over30Pressed"];
      filters = {
        "driving": {
           "allPressed":false,
           "under15Pressed":false,
           "under30Pressed":false,
           "over30Pressed":false
        },
        "tram": {
            "allPressed":false,
            "under15Pressed":false,
            "under30Pressed":false,
            "over30Pressed":false
        },
        "walking": {
            "allPressed":false,
            "under15Pressed":false,
            "under30Pressed":false,
            "over30Pressed":false
        },
        "isFilterActive": false
    }
    //state declared here
    }

}
```

I want to access the variables `transport_options` and `pressed_percentages` in a function that I define after the constructor:

```
resetPressed = () => {

    this.transport_options.forEach(function (transport_option) {
        this.pressed_percentages.forEach(function (pressed_percentage) {
            filters[transport_option][pressed_percentage] = false;
        })
    });

    //additional business logic
}
```

My problem is this: when I call `resetPressed`, I get the message `"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.pressed_percentages')`. However, `this.transport_options` does not trigger any error message.

So my question is: why does `this.transport_options` work, but `this.pressed_percentages` throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you also share the code where you have called this function?

Looks like **this** scope is changed

Comment: I call it in `render() {
        
        return (
            
                        <TouchableHighlight
                            underlayColor={'transparent'}
                            onPress={() => this.resetPressed()}>
                            <Text>Reset</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>`

Answer (score 0):

This must be the issues, in which your function is not binded. try using arrow operator to define your function or use `bind` function as it is used in following example.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.transport_options = ["driving", "tram", "walking"];
        this.pressed_percentages = ["allPressed", "under15Pressed","under30Pressed", "over30Pressed"];
      this.filters = {
        "driving": {
           "allPressed":false,
           "under15Pressed":false,
           "under30Pressed":false,
           "over30Pressed":false
        },
        "tram": {
            "allPressed":false,
            "under15Pressed":false,
            "under30Pressed":false,
            "over30Pressed":false
        },
        "walking": {
            "allPressed":false,
            "under15Pressed":false,
            "under30Pressed":false,
            "over30Pressed":false
        },
        "isFilterActive": false
    }

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.transport_options)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In callbacks also you have to bind your functions, like this.

```
resetPressed = () => {

    this.transport_options.forEach((transport_option)=> {
        this.pressed_percentages.forEach((pressed_percentage) =>{
            this.filters[transport_option][pressed_percentage] = false;
        })
    });

    //additional business logic
}
```

For more explanation please refer [event handling react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get the same error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.pressed_percentages')

Comment: I got your issue, this issue is still related to bind. You are passing ordinary function as call backs. 
try passing arrow operator functions or bind the callbacks, like this


resetPressed = () => {

    this.transport_options.forEach((transport_option) =>{
        this.pressed_percentages.forEach((pressed_percentage) =>{
            filters[transport_option][pressed_percentage] = false;
        })
    });

    //additional business logic
}

Comment: I tried different approaches described in https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html - binding, class fields and arrow functions. None of these work. For me, the issue is not that `resetPressed()` is not called; my problem is that `this.resetPercentages` is undefined.

Comment: have you changed the callbacks as well, as it is mentioned above?